# How do I access Windows GUI File Menus via a separate Java process?

Tags: java, windows, perl, user-interface

I currently have a Perl process that uses [Win32 GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~erngui/Win32-GuiTest-1.3/GuiTest.pm) that accesses the file menu of a separate Windows GUI process.  Both processes run on the same Windows (2K3x64) server.  I would like to port it to Java, and have the Java process manipulate the Windows GUI.

I have looked into Abbot, JaWin, and JAB, but they all seem to be geared towards Swing, AWT, Java-manipulating-Java-Windows, etc.

The Win32 GuiTest methods that the Perl process uses are:

```
FindWindowLike()
GetWindowText()
SetForeGroundWindow()
SendKeys()
GetFocus()
GetActiveWindow()
```

While a Java code sample or linked example would be the ideal answer, any MFC-related suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, IMO, is to use [JNI (Java Native Interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Check out some Win32 UI-related [samples here.](http://www.atwistedweb.com/java/jni.html). And [Sun JNI TOC here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html).

The GUI test methods that you list sound like they map almost 1-to-1 to the Win32 API. [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example, is a function defined in the User32.dll...

You should also look into JNA: https://github.com/twall/jna or J/Direct: http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0193.shtml

Comment: Thanks!  However, I'm going to continue to look for a solution that doesn't require me to learn C and be tied to self-compiled DLL's.  I will give the linked example a try, though.

Comment: JNI doesn't require C or self-compiled DLLs. Sorry to mislead you with that example. You can import and use Win32 DLLs w/o much trouble.

Comment: On further research I see why there's so many wrappers to User32... You should also look into JNA: https://github.com/twall/jna or J/Direct: http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0193.shtml

Comment: Update: Unfortunately, I was able to get Perl 5.8.8 with Win32::GuiTest working on the Windows 2008 R2 server, so the business-case-justification went out the window.  Thanks for the (future) references, though, Paul!